# How can I change the position of my page number ONLY for one section?

Tags: header-footer, numbering, memoir, page-numbering

The thesis of my university requires the pagination in the following way:

(1) Pages preceding the introduction (acknowledgment, table of contents, list of tables, etc.) are to be numbered with lower-case Roman numerals beginning with ii, iii, iv, etc., ***centered at the bottom*** of the page at least one double-space below the last line of text and one inch above the bottom of the page.

(2) The body of the thesis or dissertation ... Each page should be
numbered ***at the upper right*** within the right margin...

How can I solve this problem, especially for the table of context, since other section, I can manually create other file?

For example, I have tried this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\copypagestyle{chapter}{plain}
\makeevenfoot{chapter}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{chapter}{}{}{}
\makeevenhead{chapter}{}{}{\thepage}
\makeoddhead{chapter}{}{}{\thepage}
\copypagestyle{part}{plain}
\makeevenfoot{part}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{part}{}{}{}
\makeevenhead{part}{}{}{\thepage}
\makeoddhead{part}{}{}{\thepage}
\makeevenfoot{headings}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{headings}{}{}{}
\makeevenhead{headings}{}{}{\thepage}
\makeoddhead{headings}{}{}{\thepage}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\begin{abstract}
Abstract\\
Abstract\\
Abstract\\
\end{abstract}•
\newpage

\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\setcounter{page}{1}
\chapter{One}
blah blah
\section{A}
\section{B}
\chapter{Two}
\section{A}
\section{B}
\end{document}}
```

This solves the problem for i, ii, iii and 1, 2, 3. However, how can I change the positions of i, ii, iii to meet (1) that centered at the bottom?

I appreciate it if anyone can help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. I suspect `\frontmatter` might be a good starting point, but your document class might not support it. Thus, a simple MWE would be useful to get answers.

Comment: Are you sure that the first page of chapters is also supposed to have a number on the upper right? This is quite an odd format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite simple to do.  Basically you just need to use the `plain` page style for the `\frontmatter` and then redefine the `headings` pagestyle for the rest of the document.  I've aliased the `chapter` pagestyle to be `headings` after the `\mainmatter` command. This way it will redefine the `\chapter` page style only after the table of contents etc.  It's an odd format to have the number of the first page  of a chapter be on the upper right (usually it's in the bottom centre). If you need the first pages of chapters to be at the bottom centre, just remove the `\aliaspagestyle` command.  Since it appears you need all pages to have the same header, I've added the `oneside` option to the `\documentclass` command.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % package for dummy text (not needed)

\makepagestyle{headings}
\makeevenfoot{headings}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{headings}{}{}{}
\makeevenhead{headings}{}{}{\thepage}
\makeoddhead{headings}{}{}{\thepage}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\frontmatter
\begin{abstract}
\kant[1-2]
\end{abstract}
\newpage

\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\pagestyle{headings}
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{headings} % remove this if chapter beginnings are different

\chapter{One}
\kant
\section{A}
\section{B}
\chapter{Two}
\kant
\section{A}
\section{B}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: @Shaoyi If this solved your problem it's helpful to "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark icon beside the voting buttons.