# Change the position of page numbering after mainmatter onesided book

Tags: page-numbering, single-sided, book-class

This question is similar with the following link : Related, but twosided book and didn't work when i tried: [Change position of page number after frontmatter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/452666/221368).

My requirements :

1. Preliminary pages, placed after `\frontmatter` : lowercase Roman numerals, centered
   in the bottom of the page. Begin with the number (i) on the second page
   or second cover (i have 2 covers). (Solved)
2. Text (Chapter 1-N), placed after `\mainmatter` : Arabic numerals, upper right-hand corner. (Unsolved)
3. Invisible page number on each first page of chapter. (Solved)

My attempt for number 2 : i tried to use `\pagestyle{headings}` under `\mainmatter`. It works, but the chapter name on the left header annoys me and i want to get rid of it. Then i tried using `\pagestyle{plain}` to hide that but didn't work (i know this is dumb). My point to this question is only to remove the chapter/section/subsection on the upper left header like [this](https://ibb.co/18zrkjB)

btw, i'll try to handle number 1&3. Can you help me for number 2 without chapter name on the left header and without ruins everything?

Let me know if my question is unclear. I need this answer. Please help me i beg of you. Thanks in advance.